# SQL Error Code error: 42S22. why am I getting this error on the page error code 500. Laravel FWC

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country_code' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `posts`.*, `categories`.`parent_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `posts` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`category_id` where `categories`.`parent_id` = 200 and `country_code` = EN and `category_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 460, 461, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682) and `verified_email` = 1 and `verified_phone` = 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Xbo.png)

when adding another country

```
{"success":false,"message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country_code' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `country_code` =
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p86Tk.png)

when

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.country_code' in 'where clause' (SQL: SELECT sc.id, c.parent_id, count(*) as total
                FROM posts as a
                INNER JOIN categories as sc ON sc.id=a.category_id AND sc.active=1
                INNER JOIN categories as c ON c.id=sc.parent_id AND c.active=1
                WHERE a.country_code = :countryCode AND (a.verified_email=1 AND a.verified_phone=1) AND a.archived!=1 AND a.deleted_at IS NULL
                GROUP BY sc.id)
```

Comment: In which table do you have country_code column? Also string should be enclosed in quotes country_code = 'EN'

Comment: Please add more detail to this question, we can't guess the code from the error alone, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and re edit this post so we can answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your database table named 'posts' and confirm if a column named 'country_code' is present.

If 'country_code' is present, then consider changing `WHERE a.country_code = :countryCode` to `WHERE a.country_code = '$countryCode'`.

Note that I removed ':' from ':countryCode' and I replaced it with '$' in '$countryCode', with the assumption that you have a variable named $countryCode in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share more information about your data structure. That errors mean your column `country_code` does not exist